# On Windows MSVC, is it possible to merge some .obj into one .obj? If yes, how should I do that?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, linker

For example, there is three object files `a.obj b.obj c.obj` just compiled out with `cl`, and it is desired to combine them into one `combined.obj`.

A comment of an SO question points out that on *nix it's possible to do this kind of thing with `ld`. However, `cl` and `link` all seems only support `.exe`, `.dll` and `.lib` as output.

---

The whole procedure of what I want to do with the combined object file as follows:

1. `a.obj b.obj c.obj` `->` `combined.obj`
2. `combined.obj d.obj e.obj` `->` `executable.exe`

---

**My problem is solved.** `a.obj b.obj c.obj` use some variables and functions yet to be linked, and I thought that `.lib` can't tolerant missing functions since it is a library, but in fact it is OK. I can just merge them into an `.lib` file:

```
lib *.obj /OUT:combined.lib
```

Comment: Something wrong with putting them in a .lib file ? That is, after all, what they're for: collecting object code into a single library.

Comment: There may be a tool available for merging object files. But, generally, this is what an object *library* is for.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, they lacks some unlinked functions, so it's not OK to put them in a library.

Comment: @Aoyama You can stuff *any* object code into a .lib file. external dependencies make no difference. Ultimately the consumer of the lib will have to finish that off by providing anything still missing.  A DLL, different story, but a regular archive lib is literally just a package of object code.

Comment: @Aoyama If your last comment is about the ability to do link-time code generation and the like - MSVC *can* do that with object libraries, if you tell it to build those libraries with that option in mind.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you, I didn't know that `.lib` can tolerant missing stuff! Now my problem is solved, I can compiled them into one `.lib`.

Comment: Take note to what Adrian said. If you're looking to build with LTCG for release builds, you need to make sure the objs you're stuffing into your .lib were adequately configured to do so.

Comment: Please write an answer and mark it. This is not a forum, and others seeking for help with similar issues will not bother to come here if there is no accepted answer.

Comment: @thebusybee The answer hasn't been found yet, however there is a workaround and I've edited it into the question description. I have benefited  from many "unanswered" questions like this, where there are great stuff in the comments and the question description, and I think if anyone with similar issues came up with this in Google they would came in to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not, but it is convenient to merge them into an `.lib`:

```
lib *.obj /OUT:combined.lib
```

Comment: This is not a merge, this is bundling. The object files are simply placed into an archive, much as with `ar` in GCC-based toolchains. You can even unpack the `.lib` files MSVC generates using tools like 7-Zip and `ar`.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* apply the method employed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980126/476371) also to the COFF files created by `cl.exe`, *provided that* your build of `ld` supports the respective input and output formats and those formats lend themselves to the process.

What you can do in such a case is this (and yes `$INPUTS` means you can give multiple object files as you wanted):

```
ld --oformat pe-x86-64 -r $INPUTS -o $OUTPUT
```

The `--oformat pe-x86-64` (aka AMD64, x64 on Windows) is necessary whenever the `ld` has been built with a different default output format.

If that's the case and you *didn't* give `--oformat` you will get something like:

```
ld: relocatable linking with relocations from format pe-x86-64 (input.obj) to format elf64-x86-64 (output.obj) is not supported
```

**However** the process doesn't work for all input/output format combinations, as I learned with `ld` 2.34 on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
ld: relocatable linking with relocations from format pe-i386 (input.obj) to format pe-i386 (output.obj) is not supported
```

**NB:** At this point I had no luck to get this to work with `lld-link` or `ld.lld` (both available through modern VS versions), though.

PS: Another tool to be aware of would be [`objconv` by Agner Fog](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) of general performance optimization fame (it currently doesn't seem to implement this exact feature, though, it appears).